# "from django.shortcuts import render" gets me an error (red wavy line)

Tags: python, django

I have a decent amount of experience with Django, but recently I opened one of my old Django projects and realized there was something wrong with it. I looked through the files and I found that there were red wavy lines under: `from django.shortcuts import render`, `from django.views import View`, indicating that there is an error. I did not change anything I do not know what caused it. When I run the server I also get an error saying "name 'request' is not defined". Pleae help, here is the code:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View

class Index(View): #creating different methods 
    def get(self, requst, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, 'landing/index.html')
```

Comment: Is request spelled wrong in the function signature of your code as well?

Comment: **Typo**: You've misspelled `requst`, it should be `request`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use virtual enviroment and have all required packages installed (e.g. django).

Does "venv" directory or something like that exist in your project? If so, activate it by `.\venv\Script\activate` on Windows or 'source venv/bin/activate' on linux.

If it doesn't exist, create it with e.g. virtualenv, activate it and install packages via `pip`

Comment: I have my virtual environment activated. I ran "pip install django" again just to make sure, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, that is odd, but try this:

```
import django.shortcuts.render as render
```

Comment: I just tried it but it didn't work...